# connect loose objects

Tags: mesh, objects

I want to create a kite. Four triangles and one rope but without a connection. Now I want to add a Force Field (Force) but all objects are flying confused. How can I create "one" object without connecting this five parts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

select all the individual objects and try CTRL J

Comment: this was my first try, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the other answer ...Select the rope, then select the kite, press ctrl+p and select 'object(keep transform)' in this way if you apply force field to the kite, the rope will move with the kite

i added a rigidbody to the rope with the cloth modifier and set them to the least of their masses

[check it out here](https://mega.nz/file/gQRTHQ7Q#nfN4yfFmvR5Lmpu_PNRDmWkz-H3mJ8Ttg_draZt_XLo)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: Can you share the blend file, maybe I can take a look

Comment: sure :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/ap28eociekd6b1f/kite.blend?dl=0 maybe you can check my kite_2, it does nothing :(

Comment: hey, i edited my answer with the edited blender file, not the exact thing you wanted, but the rope flies now

Comment: Hey, many thanks. One step more  :)